# How do I communicate between C++ and Flash?

Tags: c++, windows, flash, actionscript

Is there any way I can have an integration between Flash AS and C++? Let's say I have created a socket using C++ and multi-casting it to several ip addresses.

On one of the IPs I am running a Flash client. Can I receive the Multicast message (sent by MFC/C++ application) through my Flash application.

Or at least can I develop a Flash plugin (menu item) using C++?

The main objective is I just need to get my hands on anything that shows the communication/interaction between C++ and Flash.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683797/communication-between-c-and-actionscript-3 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300821/communicate-between-c-applications-and-web-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you would like to do. If you host the swf's in your application you can use the ExtenalInterface in flash via the ActiveX container. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

We are using that method in our project, check it out (open source): http://www.casparcg.com/

If you want to talk to swf's outside your application Sockets would do the job I guess.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html